# How to get all Photoshop styles?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I want to randomly apply styles to my ArtLayers.
To do this, I tested the applyStyle function.

ArtLayers.applyStyle

[image: 1]

It works!)

But to solve my task I need all styles.
I can't find it in the documentation (photoshop-javascript-ref-2020).

Can you suggest something?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jsx] and [tag:photoshop]? I would have thought they would be incompatible.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:styles]? It says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the bits about providing a [mcve] and about not posting pictures of code

Comment: @Quentin, sorry its my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the styles use this Action Manager function:

```
var allStyles = get_styles()
alert(allStyles); // ALLL the styles!
//alert(allStyles[22]); // Sunspots (texture)

function get_styles()
{
  var ref = new ActionReference(); 
  ref.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID("capp"), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt") ); 
  var appDesc = executeActionGet(ref); 
  var List = appDesc.getList(stringIDToTypeID('presetManager'));
  var list = List.getObjectValue(3).getList(charIDToTypeID('Nm  '));
  var styleNames=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
  {
    var str = list.getString(i);
    styleNames.push(str);
  }

  return styleNames;
}
```

Comment: I thought it was obvious that I was interested in styles that are in Photoshop. You have manually rewritten 3 styles into an array. And if I have 100 or 1000 of them, rewrite them for me?

Comment: @Famouse I've updated my answer. And it always helps to explain exactly what you are after ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to figure out what's going on here)

Comment: I looked at the code a bit. I didn't think it was so inconvenient to write scripts for Photoshop. It's trite to get all the styles turns out to be quite a difficult task. And the worst thing is that I can't find information about what you use.

"capp", "Ordn", "Trgt" - this is not written in the pdf documentation, it says use ScriptingListener. I used it, I see that Ordn and Trgt are called, but I did not understand what it is, and I did not find capp. What are they responsible for?

Comment: presetManager zero information in the documentation
And you are still from there, something purposefully takes with the index 3, and from there you pull the name.

In general, I will be very grateful for explanations to the code) And if you tell me the secret where you can read about it.

Comment: @Famouse Most of the time it's plain ol' JavaScript (well ECMAScript to be exact) but in order to get functionality of certain things - like accessing Styles from the preset manager - that uses Action Manager script. Which is the ugly code above. If you want to take a deep dive into [AM code](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/action-manager-scripting/m-p/11160326) then this is the best place to start. Also check out the **scriptlistener plugin** (which comes with Photoshop but isn't automatically installed)